# e(fx)clipse plugin doesn't work on Mac

Tags: java, macos, javafx, efxclipse

*You are not running your eclipse instance with Java8. The JavaFX tooling is      disabled because of this.Make Java8 the default system java or adjust your eclipse.ini to pass -vm pointing to your Java8 install.*

I have the latest JDK with Java 8 installed and it works perfectly for any other method or program in my application. However, when I try to install this plugin, I get the previous error.

I am running Mac OSX Yosemite with Eclipse Luna.

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: I had the same problem this morning. I was using JDK 1.8_u25. I updated my JDK to 1.8._u31 and it resolved the problem.

Comment: What does java -version print on the command line? It should not matter what version of java8 you are running with

Comment: This is what I get from terminal:

Comment: java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)

Comment: @Ethan that looks ok - post to our forum so that we can track down what's going on and why it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to simply download the Eclipse that is bundled with this plugin from:

http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/install.html#all-in-one
It works fine and recognizes my Java 8.

Comment: If you post to our forum we might find out what went wrong when you installed the plugin into an existing eclipse install this might help others in future as well but stackoverflow is not really suited for this type of discussion

Answer (score -2):

I use JavaFX on Luna without any Plugin... is that plugin supposed to help you with the GUI Design? if your answer is yes, you better use [SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/sb2download-2177776.html) and forget about any other plugin/software.

Also... that happens when you try to run a JavaFX program? or when you open Eclipse?

Make sure that you have the jfxrt.jar in your Java dir... if it is, import it to your current project...  i know there's something else you can check but i cant remember it rigth now. I'll write it here later.

Anyway, let me know if the previous text helped you

Comment: Reading http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html should answer why you should use the plugin

Comment: Additionally, there's no need to add jfxrt.jar in Java 8. It is included in the default classpath.

Comment: Sorry but this didn't help. As @tomsontom said, that is the use of the plugin. I have followed many tutorials and I know I have the right java version but nothing seems to work. Let me know any other suggestions you may have. Thanks

Comment: Also, the popup comes up right after I open Eclipse

Comment: Sorry for my bad answer....
How about using IntelliJ? Im currently migrating my JavaFX projects to IntelliJ and it works perfect.